# Установка linux второй системой, проблема загрузки

Tags: linux, windows, установка

Сделал установочную флешку с **ubuntu-16.04.2** Выставляю загрузку с флэшки, попадаю в меню загрузки, нажимаю `install ubuntu`, комп перегружается, но экран приветствия установщика убунту не появляется. На ноуте всё ок. Мать `asrock`, моник соединяет по `HDMI`. Может кто знает, почему так происходит?

Comment: *перегружается* — вот и проблема. причина которой — не может загрузиться/стартовать программа установки. возможно, некорректно скачан/записан/прочитан образ.

Comment: спасибо, вы от части правы, сделал образ минта, всё установилось

Answer (score 8):

Оборудование не совместимо с Linux. Чтоб загрузиться нужно попробовать опции noapic и acpi=off, а также nomodeset.

[image: загрузка в установщике]

Большая часть таких проблем решается сама во время установки и новая система загрузится без проблем.

Некоторые проблемы решаются установкой драйверов и прошивок. Например, видеокарта на процессоре AMD A4-6400 запускается нормально только на драйверах fglrx, которые ставятся отдельно. Временно запуститься поможет редактирование строки загрузки. выбрать пункт в загрузчике и нажать `E`, вместо слова quiet добавьте нужный параметр и нажмите  `F10`.

Иногда нет решения на данный момент и эти параметры прийдется оставить в загрузчике. Для этого на установленной системе отредактируйте в `/etc/default/grub`переменную `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`
.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, проблема была решена установкой минта ))))))

Comment: @eri возми в ученики, пожалуйста)

Comment: @Максим, город?

Comment: @eri не думал что ответишь))) там где я живу с айти толком нет ничего связанного. Думал может тебе человек с горящими глазами нужно на удаленку. Тебе сбросить часть работы - мне практика) Крым, г. Ялта

Comment: @Максим устанавливать убунты на компы удаленно можно конечно, но самому проще) посмотрим что есть...

Comment: @eri я не говорю про установку убунты)) я о том что я увлекаюсь linux. Сейчас немного поднакоплю что бы LPIC пройти. Просто денег нет) Помимо пингвина занимаюсь с++. У меня 2 направления по которым я двигаюсь, это администрирование серверов линукс и с++. Просто у меня нет реального опыта. Из того что я сейчас имеют, это контора спорт бет, которая платим мне 12500 РУБЛЕЙ за СИСТЕМНОГО АДМИНИСЬТРАТОРА. Больше сказали им не интерестно...

Comment: с++ тоже изучаю понемногу. dmliZXI6Kzc5MTU4MzI3MDM5

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110089/discussion-between--and-eri).